# Macro variable in sas stored process

Tags: stored-procedures, sas

I have a code in SAS.

```
proc sql;
create test as select * from test2 where user_name = &username;quit;
```

when I Run in SAS EG with  `%let username=Bob` it runs normal.
But I need to run it with stored Process (variable username is internal parameter in connected user and  I delete `%let username=Bob` from sas stored process code). 
Stored Process brake with an error.

In log file I see variable:

`_username=Bob` but code in stored process can not find it. How to use this variable in SAS Stored process code? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your own SAS code, you use a macro variable `username`, but in your stored process, the user name is available in the reserved macro variable `_username`. The underscore is really part of the variable name, so you should write `&_username`.

For more information, you can read [the documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/stpug/62758/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p184mqqbi9w6qjn1q0619x19eg02.htm) or you can consult the log after inserting

```
%put _automatic_;
```

in your code, to print all macro variables SAS provided for you.

Remark: As the automatic macro variables in a stored process differ from that in a local SAS session, if you want to use the same code in both, you often need some `%if %then %else` logic.